# Deploy then access my ASP.NET web application which contain a WCF, will return "You do not have permission to view this directory or page."

Tags: azure, wcf, deployment, azure-web-app-service

1- I have created an ASP.NET web application which contain a WCF service, as follow:-
[image]

2- Then i create a new azure web app @ this URL `https://ourcompanynametestrer.azurewebsites.net`.

3- Then i deploy the web application inside the azure web app:-

```
az webapp deployment source config-zip --resource-group "ourcompanynameSharePoint" --name "ourcompanynameTestRER" --src "C:\WebApplication5.zip".
```

But when i try to access the azure web app, i got this error:-

[image]

Also when i try to access the WCF service @ `https://ourcompanynametestrer.azurewebsites.net/service1.svc`, i got this error:-

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /service1.svc
```

Also when i try to request the logs using this url `/api/deployments/latest/log` i got the following:-

```
{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"No log found for 'latest'.","ExceptionType":"System.IO.FileNotFoundException","StackTrace":"   at Kudu.Core.Deployment.DeploymentManager.GetLogEntries(String id) in C:\\Kudu Files\\Private\\src\\master\\Kudu.Core\\Deployment\\DeploymentManager.cs:line 98\r\n   at Kudu.Services.Deployment.DeploymentController.GetLogEntry(String id) in C:\\Kudu Files\\Private\\src\\master\\Kudu.Services\\Deployment\\DeploymentController.cs:line 375"}
```

Comment: Hi, if you are using Visual Studio. You can right click your mouse and use that to publish.

Comment: It seems like this is an known issue. [Have a look of this](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/11848#issuecomment-407208261)

Comment: Hi, still have the problem?